# Check all placeholders in PreparedStatement are filled

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a user-generated SQL-statement with placeholders (like `SELECT * FROM films WHERE stars > ? AND length > ?`) and arbitrary amount of inputs for values supposed to be inserted. I'm iterating through inputs to insert all of them into `PreparedStatement`, but I don't know on compile-time how many placeholders in `PreparedStatement` nor how many inputs user provided.

As far as I understand, supposed way to go is to catch `SQLException` on `preparedStatement.execute()`, which tells me that "no value specified for placeholder ...", but it doesn't work for me for many reasons:

- I don't know on compile time which DB will be used, `SQLException` can be anything
- Not filled placeholder should be handled in one way (particularly this is OK situation) and lost connection in another way (this is really error)

Also searching for `?` in generated query doesn't work because it will fail on following statement: `SELECT * FROM films WHERE title = 'Who Framed Roger Rabbit?'`

So, is there any way to check completeness of `PreparedStatement` before execution?

Comment: And what are these "obvious reasons" why getting the number of ``?``s is not working? Catching that exception is also valid, since the query is never even sent to the dbms but created during the querys compilation.

Comment: Why can the user send more inputs than you are supposed to use on the backend?

Comment: @f1sh updated question to be more clear

Comment: @dambros because application doesn't know anything about this table

Comment: See if `ParameterMetaData` helps you : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData()

Comment: The second to the last sentence is confusing, it sounds like you're trying to replace the ? placeholders in the sql string, which is at odds with how PreparedStatement expects to be used. Also spring has a lot of features (named parameters for preparedStatements, sql exception translation that uses db-specific sqlstate to create meaningful exceptions) that would make your job easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `java.sql.ParameterMetaData`, it should contain all sorts of information on your `PreparedStatement` (including parameter count).

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = ...
ParameterMetaData metadata = pstmt.getParameterMetaData();
int pcount = metadata.getParameterCount();
```

`pcount` will contain the number of parameters. Note, that `pstmt.getParameterMetaData()` **will connect to the database**.

So when iterating your input and binding parameters you can assure (**at runtime**) that all parameters are bound.

Comment: Thank you and @JoopEggen. I looked at pstmt.getMetaData(), but didn't realized getParameterMetaData() is different method.